# Android production build signature issue

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have two apps which communicate with each other using broadcast receivers. Both the Apps work fine when I run the application in debug build. I have a custom permission which is used by both the apps and the protection level of this permission is set to normal in debug build.

But when I change the protection level of the permission in both the Apps to signature for production build the other application does not receive the broadcast and throws an exception: 
W/PackageManager(2946): Not granting permission com.example.CUSTOM_PERMISSION to package com.example.android (protectionLevel=2 flags=0x88be44)

Can someone please help as this a showstopper.

Comment: How are you signing the apps?

Comment: One of the Apps I have signed with production keystore and then with google using the command (java -jar google_sign/signapk.jar google_sign/platform.x509.pem google_sign/platform.pk8 Desktop/MY_APK.apk Desktop/MY_APK.google.signed.apk). The other app I have signed with production keystore.

Answer (score 0):

The signatures do not match.

Suppose your app A is signed with certs 1 and 2 and app B with only cert 1.

Now A can get the signature-level permission for B since it is signed with cert 1.

B cannot get the signature-level permission for A since it is not signed with both certs 1 and 2.

Comment: For my previous versions this procedure was working fine but for this current build it is not working.\

Comment: Suppose App B is signed with cert 1 which I dont have(App signed by Samsung), then how can I sign App A with cert 1.